# Protecting an internal AWS API Gateway from access

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I'm writing an internal API in an AWS Serverless architecture. This API should be used by several other internal services, and is basically an API Gateway with a bunch of Lambdas behind it. I am worried about external access to that Gateway.

I wonder how it is best to protect my API from external access. I could use API Keys, but they don't strike me as very secure in the long term, or I could try putting the API Gateway in a VPC, but that would further complicate the behavior of the Lambdas behind it. Or could it be that choosing to use an API Gateway was a mistake in the first place?

Comment: *"putting the API Gateway in a VPC, but that would further complicate the behavior of the Lambdas behind it"*  Putting API Gateway inside the VPC has no impact on where any Lambda functions it invokes are located... so it's not clear what this means.

Answer (score 0):

Application Gateway is OK for your use case.

You can use an [API Gateway Private Endpoint](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/) to expose private API endpoints inside your VPC. Private endpoints were introduced in Jun/2018.

Comment: As of now, I don't have any assets to secure, so I'm not using a VPC. it's just few lambdas that should be chained together. should i create a VPC just for protecting the API?

Comment: There should be a default VPC already. The VPC itself has no costs.